# Ограничить движение по y. C# Unity 2D

Tags: c#

У меня есть скрипт для патрулирования области и преследования персонажа, если он подойдёт близко. Проблема состоит в том, что когда игрок прыгает, патрулирующий объект начинает взлетать. Как мне ограничить движение патрулирующего объекта по Y? (фрагмент скрипта ниже)
P.S. point - точка патрулирования.

```
void Chill()
{
    speed = 1;
    if (transform.position.x > point.position.x + positionOfPatrol)
    {
        moveingRight = false;
    }
    else if(transform.position.x < point.position.x - positionOfPatrol)
    {
        moveingRight = true;
    }
    if(moveingRight)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    }

}
void Angry()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    speed = 2;
}
void GoBack()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, point.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    speed = 3;
}
```

}

Comment: Unity? Добавьте соответствующий тег к вопросу

Comment: Да, юнька, а что ещё собвственно...

Comment: "Что ещё собственно" - Вы так спрашиваете, будто на C# пишут только в рамках Unity

Comment: может, кто-то мне уже поможет, а не будет ненужные вопросы задавать...?